# Azure Java/Scala ServiceBus consumer, error handling with retries

Tags: java, azure, scala, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have simple servicebus consumer:

```
val consumeFunc = (context: ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext) => consumeMessageOrder(context, onConsumed)
val queueName = messageType match {
  case MessageBusService.Order => config.ordersQueueName
}

new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
  .connectionString(config.connectionString)
  .processor()
  .queueName(queueName)
  .processMessage { context =>
    consumeFunc(context)
  }
  .processError(context => processErrorOrder(context, countdownLatch))
  .buildProcessorClient()
```

and error handling method:

```
  def processErrorOrder(context: ServiceBusErrorContext, countdownLatch: CountDownLatch): Unit = {
    import ServiceBusFailureReason._
    context.getException match {
      case e: ServiceBusException
          if List(MESSAGING_ENTITY_DISABLED, MESSAGING_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, UNAUTHORIZED).contains(
            e.getReason
          ) =>
        log.error(s"An unrecoverable error occurred. Stopping processing with reason ${e.getReason} ${e.getMessage}")
        countdownLatch.countDown()
      case e: ServiceBusException =>
        log.error(s"Error source ${context.getErrorSource}, reason ${e.getReason}, message: ${e}")
    }
  }
```

its in scala, but code is based on official tutorial [AzureDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues)
I can not find a way, to create some retry policy here, how to handle retries here and if on failed X retried land failing message to deadletter queue ?

thanks

Comment: One way would be to do it in the processErrorOrder function. You could have it so it catches the exception (general) and then increase a counter. Whenever the exception happens again, the counter will have been increased and therefore exit retry login -> go to deadLetter Queue. That's one way I guess. You could also create separate function that's called before processErrorOrder and do similar logic.

Comment: @GamingFelix thanks but hmm it just does not work this way.. I dont get it. I increased this countdown to 5.  Added countdownLatch.countDown() to both cases in process order  pattern match, in logs still I see only 1 try, and this message does not even lands in deadletters queue :(

Comment: Are you catching all/general exceptions? It sounds like it could be a problem. You do a matching of exceptions, but what if the exception is not a ServiceBusException? You should also catch general exceptions and log it, perhaps you can see then what is causing it.